# select inside another select doesn't show everything

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to select data from my database and images as well.

Both work separately but if I paste the image select inside the while loop, it shows only one row of the database.

This is the first select:

```
$example = 5;
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT id, name, etc.. FROM cards WHERE example = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("i", $example);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
while ($record = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
?>

//using the records here like this: 
<h4 class="card-category text-gray"><b><?php echo $record['job']; ?></b><br></h4>

//more records here

<?php
$sql = "SELECT id, image FROM cardimages WHERE cardid = ?";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$id = $record['id'];
$stmt->bind_param('i', $id);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();

if (mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) != null) {
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
$image = $row['image'];
$data[] = $row;
?>
```

Below is where I show the results:

```
<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg show" id="myModal<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
<span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
</button>
</div>
<div class="modal-body" id="dynamic-content">
<?php
echo "<img src='" . $image . "' class='img-fluid' />";
?>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Ending the while loop:

```
}
} else {
echo '<h5>No image availabe</h5>';
}
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: You have a syntax error where you try to display HTML

Comment: You really need to format your code and separate HTML from PHP. You overwrite your variables inside the loop but you can't even see it. Use proper IDE with syntax highlighting and formatting.

Comment: I don't have error in my code, Just forgot to close the div here.

Comment: No. You can't mix PHP and HTML. You need to separate them.

Comment: What do you mean? I have a php file, with separated html and php parts. I must put the records inside the html code to show them.

Comment: Have one file with HTML and another with PHP. When you want to switch between PHP and HTML context you need to open and close using PHP tags `<?php ?>`

Comment: I'm using those tags and everything works fine except that thing I asked in the question.

Comment: You never close PHP code before displaying `<h4`. You have `?>` in a random place in your code. Either this is not the real code or you have syntax errors in your code.

Comment: I would recommend learning PDO instead of mysqli, because it is simpler and less chance you will be making typos like the one you have made now. Even better would be to use a proper PHP framework. As I said before the reason why you are having problems is because you are overwriting your PHP variables and it's difficult to spot the mistakes for you due to the messy code.

Comment: Edited my question with some more details in my code. Could you help me with the image selecting part. What should I change there?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As was pointed out in a comment by @dharman, the variable `$result` is getting overwritten inside the loop.

```
$result = $stmt->get_result();
```

ie.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT id, name, etc.. FROM cards WHERE example = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("i", $example);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
```

and then later in the code:

```
$sql = "SELECT id, image FROM cardimages WHERE cardid = ?";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$id = $record['id'];
$stmt->bind_param('i', $id);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
```

If you store your result in the loop as another variable then both loops should run properly.

Comment: How does that help with the problem?

Comment: You mean I just need to change $result to something else in the second select and that's all?

Comment: You were right, $result was the problem. I just simply changed it to another variable in my second select and it works fine now. Thank you!

Comment: @admin you're welcome! took me longer than i thought to see the problem :-)